# How can I specify an environment for salt's top.sls file from Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, saltstack

I want to use Vagrant to deploy a range of boxes with salt.

I've looked through all the available Vagrant salt options available in salty-vagrant (now built in) and I can't see any that would let me specify which "environment" to use, as referenced in salt.sls

```
dev:
  'webserver*dev*':
    - webserver
  'db*dev*':
    - db
qa:
  'webserver*qa*':
    - webserver
  'db*qa*':
    - db
```

I want to be able to have the same salt directory for all my machine types, and use different Vagrant files (or even parameters to vagrant) to determine whether I'm building a dev box, a qa box, a db box, etc.

Is there any way to pass this information from Vagrant to salt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to pass information to the minion in Vagrant is the minon file. You can [define grains in the minion file](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/grains.html#grains-in-the-minion-config), but also [the ID of the minon](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/minion.html#std:conf_minion-id).

I set up a set of Vagrant boxes myself using the following approach. Here some excerpts:

```
# top.sls (excerpt)
base:
  'webserver*':
    - webserver
  'db*':
    - db
```

In this example the `webserver*` and `db*` entries are the host names. I found that Vagrant sets up the hostname of the box very late (at least when I tried it), so I passed a minon file with the hard coded minon name in vagrant:

```
# Vagrantfile (excerpt)
config.vm.synced_folder "salt/roots/", "/srv/"
config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
  salt.minion_config = "salt/minion"
  salt.run_highstate = true
end
```

And the minion file:

```
# minion (excerpt)
id: webservertest
```

You can also define grain information in the minion file.

I hope this helps.

Br,
Alexander.